# How to generate random polygons in Python that do not have bow ties (intersections)

Tags: python, math, polygon, intersection

How can you generate polygones with a random number of sides that don't have bow ties/intersections in Python.

Comment: This question is lacking a lot of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a normal polygon, and then undo each bow tie.

A bow tie looks like:

```
          b
     a    _____
_____    /
     \  /
      \/
      /\___
_____/ d 
     c
```

When you encounter a bow tie, replace the sides going from a to d and from c to b by sides going from a to b and from c to d.

There are several ways to recognize the existence of the bow tie, the simplest may be that a, b, c, d is a bow tie iff the sum of lengths ad + cb is greater than ab + cd.